# How to stop progress bar animation halfway using Keyframes

Tags: css, progress-bar, css-animations

I'm trying to load the progress bar up to a certain percentage. Whatever that percentage is, the progress bar will stop at that specific color animation specified in the keyframes.
How can i get it to work.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="progress-bar">
        <span style="width:50%">
            <span class="progress-value"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
        <span><strong>CSS</strong></span>
    <br/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .progress-bar {
        background-color: lightgray;
        border-radius: 1.25em;
        width: 300px;
        height: 16px;
        width: 50vw;
    }
    .progress-bar > span {
        display: flex;
    }
    .progress-value {
        background-color: #673ab7;
        transition: 0.3s all linear;
        border-radius: 1.25em;
        height: 16px;
        width: 50vw;
        animation: progress-color 3s linear forwards;
        -webkit-animation: progress-color 3s linear forwards;
    }
    /* animation */
    @keyframes progress-color {
        0% {
            width: 0;
        }
        50% {
            width: 30%;
            background: purple;
        }
        100% {
            background: green;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes progress-color {
        0% {
            width: 0;
        }
        50% {
            width: 30%;
            background:red;
        }
        100% {
            background: green;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
```

Here's my codepen 
https://codepen.io/mingsterism/pen/xJgePK

Comment: You might need the help of javascript or jquery to trigger the `animation-play-state` property to pause the animation at the specified `keyframe`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that where you have specified the animation is 100% completed under the @keyframes , there you must specify red as the color, which you have specified as the color you wish when the bar reaches 50%, while the rest of of the code is fine. Replace your piece of code with this one below and tell, is this what you want ?

```
 @keyframes progress-color {
        0% {
            width: 0;
        }
        50% {
            width: 30%;
            background: green;
        }
        100% {
            background: red;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes progress-color {
        0% {
            width: 0;
        }
        50% {
            width: 30%;
            background: green;
        }
        100% {
            background: red;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want the bar to stop at the color at which the width is specified. In my example, i did `<span style="width:50%">` so at 50% the color should be between red and green.